# Python-Sphinx documentation: link source code

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I have a dictionary that represent a schema (JSON-Schema to be more precise).

Sometimes the schema gets complex and in the documentation I need to link to it in order to give a better picture.

I have the `viewcode` extension enabled, I tried the following with no luck:

```
.. data:: netjsonconfig.backends.openvpn.schema.schema

.. automodule:: netjsonconfig.backends.openvpn.schema
```

The dictionary python path is `netjsonconfig.backends.openvpn.schema.schema`.

Is it possible to achieve this? If yes how?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.. literalinclude:: your_json_filename.json
    :language: json
```

You can even select a part of this file to display by

```
.. literalinclude:: your_json_filename.json
    :language: json
    :lines: 18-43
```

This displays the lines 18 to 43 of *your_json_filename.json*.

Comment: I'd like to link, not include, because the schema definition is too long, I didn't want to link github because repo URL might change so I would have liked sphinx to generate the page automatically with the viewcode extension

Comment: I understand. I don't know any way to to this. A compromise could be creating a my_json.rst with a header and this literalinclude. Then link to it with a toctree